# CSS / Div container margins issue

Tags: html, css

I have a container div set to a fixed position at top of page and several relative position divs scrollable within the container. I can set margin left, right and bottom. But the top margin is ignored and runs up against the top of the container. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#container {
position: fixed;
width: 32rem; 
height: 32rem;
background-color: #000000;
overflow: hidden;
}

#div1 {
position: relative;
width: 30em;
height: 40em;
margin: 5rem 1rem 5rem 1rem; 


<div id="container">
<div id="div1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `rem` for the margin? Did you try `px`?

Comment: This should work, to be more clear, do you want the div to have margin, or the container?

Comment: You are missing a closing `}` after your `div1` styling. Not sure if it matters.

Comment: I didn't include above it but had the left, right, top and bottom set to auto this, I think confused it but thank you all for your input, very much appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `overflow:hidden` and change `height:22em` in `#div1`

I think you want something like this and I hope it will helps you.

```css
#container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 32rem; 
  height: 32rem;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}


#div1 {
    height: 22em;
    margin: 5rem 1rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 30em;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="div1">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the desired output? http://jsfiddle.net/t9rkpspu/

```
#container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 32rem; 
  height: 32rem;
  background-color: #000000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#div1 {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  width: 30em;
  height: 40em;
  margin: 5rem 1rem 5rem 1rem; 
}
```